# Changes on backend does not reflect to store

Tags: magento2, backend, stores

I am running Magento 2.3.2.

For about two weeks now in several parts of Magento when our team makes changes via backend it does not reflect on the website. Testing multiple stuff we found out that sometimes we have to change to store 1 view and apply the change, then it works.

Things I have to make clear to help to find a solution:

- We do not run multiple stores yet, but **Magento is set up for multiple stores**;
- Our "super technical team" (lol) makes lots of changes via Magmi (direct database) and backend and mistakes are constantly done.

I believe that some change has been done without telling me and I have to set back a relation that was broken, but I don´t know-how. Help :)

Thanks !!!

Gustavo Ulysses

Comment: Have you considered running single store mode for now https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/store-mode-single.html

Comment: @DominicXigen thank you for the reply but this is a regular store under production and I am affraid about making such change. Do you have any other tip? We do have dev environment, but it is not buggy because operators and technicians does not make these bizarre editions. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You will not lose any data switching. You will prevent data and config being saved under wrong scope. Indexing will be faster. The alternative is sql queries to remove data and basically reset everything to default main configuration. I can provide these but are more destructive.

Comment: Dear @DominicXigen I could not solve this issue yet. I tested moving to single store on a test environment and there were many problems - unfortunately not a possible solution. Other ideas ?